# Envio ajax com notificação

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, notificação

Bom dia pessoal, estou com um problema em um teste, ao cadastra eu retorno uma notificação, só que a notificação da apenas uma mensagem, ou seja, mensagem de sucesso, não consigo por uma mensagem de erro, tipo um if else, e eu queira saber se não é uma gambiarra o que eu fiz, não entendo muito de ajax e jquery, mas ta funcionando kkk, queria sabe se foi a melhor opção! pois vou seguir com esse código pra insert, update e delete!

```
    <form id="cadastrarUsuario" action="" method="POST" class="form-group">
                Nome: <br>
                <input required type="text" name ="nome_usuario"><br>
                Sobrenome: <br>
                <input required type="text" name ="sobrenome_usuario"><br>
                <hr>
                <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
            </form>

    <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
    <script src="js/notificationFx.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

    $('#cadastrarUsuario').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formDados = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url:'addUsuario.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:formDados,
            cache:false,
            contentType:false,
            processData:false,
            success:function(data){
  if(data == "salvo"){
    $('#cadastrarUsuario').trigger("reset");
                            var notification = new NotificationFx({
                            wrapper : document.body,
                            message : '<p>Deu Certo</p>',
                            layout : 'growl',
                            effect : 'scale',
                            type : 'notice', // notice, warning, error or success
                            ttl : 6000,
                            onClose : function() { return false; },
                            onOpen : function() { return false; }
                            });
                            notification.show();
  }
  else{
    $('#cadastrarUsuario').trigger("reset");
                            var notification = new NotificationFx({
                            wrapper : document.body,
                            message : '<p>Deu Erro</p>',
                            layout : 'growl',
                            effect : 'scale',
                            type : 'notice', // notice, warning, error or success
                            ttl : 6000,
                            onClose : function() { return false; },
                            onOpen : function() { return false; }
                            });
                            notification.show();
  }
},
            dataType:'html'
        });
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

Php

```
 <?php 
$nome = $_POST['nome_usuario'];
$sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome_usuario'];
 try{
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','@0202','ajax');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `usuario` (`idusuario`,`nomeusuario`,`sobreusuario`) VALUES (NULL,'{$nome}','{$sobrenome}')";

    $mysqli->query($sql);
    echo "salvo";
  }
  catch(Exception $e){
    $retorno = "Erro ao salvar. ".$e->getMessage();
    echo $retorno;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O PHP não tem nenhum return, esse é o problema. No ajax, na linha:

```
success:function(data){
```

"data" vai ser o que você tiver retornado do PHP. Por exemplo, digamos que você queira saber se a query foi inserida com sucesso. Você pode colocar o código dentro de um bloco try/catch. Poderia ser assim:

PHP:

```
<?php 
  $nome = $_POST['nome_usuario'];
  $sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome_usuario'];

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','@0202','ajax');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `usuario` (`idusuario`,`nomeusuario`,`sobreusuario`) VALUES (NULL,'{$nome}','{$sobrenome}')";

    if($mysqli->query($sql) === false){
      echo mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    else{
    echo "salvo";
    }
?>
```

[Detalhes sobre o mysqli_connect_error() aqui.](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.connect-error.php)

E no ajax, dentro da função success, você faz algo como:

```
success:function(data){
  if(data == "salvo"){
    //código em caso de sucesso
  }
  else{
    alert(data);
    //ou talvez
    alert("erro ao salvar");
  }
}
```

Comment: Não ta funcionando com o notificação!

Comment: Dê detalhes sobre o erro.

Comment: Eu atualizei a minha pergunta, fiz como você mostrou, quando click em salvar ele me retorna (Deu certo) na notificação, agora quando eu erro a query propositalmente ele me retorna (Deu certo) só que não cadastra no banco obviamente mas era pra ele me retorna na notificação (Deu Erro).

Comment: Editei minha resposta. Foi um erro meu: o mysqli->query não dá throw em exception.

Comment: ficou ótimo, funcionou perfeitamente, mas parou de funciona quando eu coloquei o php mailer, pra enviar um email antes da query, não sei se ta demorando muito pra enviar o email ou alguma coisa so sei que da erro!

Comment: Fico feliz que tenha funcionado. Sobre o mailer, acredito que seja melhor fazer outra pergunta, pois já seria outro tema. Sugiro que pesquise primeiro antes de perguntar, talvez já exista solução por aí.